# How do I use tmutil to figure out what's wrong with my Time Machine?

Tags: macos, time-machine

How do I use tmutil to figure out what is wrong with my Time Machine as it keeps backing up huge amounts of data each time it back-ups although nothing has changed since the last back up?
I'm backing-up to a Drobo FS

Comment: Have you checked it is backing up to the same location, with in the drive, or is it making a new back-up?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: look in the destination folder and see if there are duplicate files.

Have you done a full system backup overnight before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
tmutil listbackups
```

to get a list of existing (completed) backups.

Then run one or both of

```
tmutil compare # to compare current drive to latest backup
tmutil compare /one/path/from/list /other/path/from/list # compare two backups
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [timedog](http://code.google.com/p/timedog/) to see what's being backed up each time.

Usage:

- Open Terminal (in /Applications/Utilities)
- `cd /Volumes/Time\ Machine/Backups.backupdb/[Computer Name]`
  Note Time Machine may be different on your system.
  Replace `[Computer Name]` with the name of your computer (see System Preferences => Sharing).
- `/path/to/timedog -d 5 -l`
  For instance, if you unzipped timedog to your Desktop, the path would be `~/Desktop/timedog`

And then look at the output